# What is wrong with this Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl, subroutine

I'm trying to implement a subroutine that calculates the d-neighbors of an input string. This is apart of an implementation of [planted motif search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planted_motif_search), but my question is much more general. Here is the code:

```
#subroutine for generating d-neighbors
sub generate_d_neighbors{
    # $sequence is the sequence to generate d-neighbors from
    # $HD is the Hamming Distance
    my ($sequence, $HD) = @_;

    for(my $i = 0; $i=$HD; $i++){
        my @l = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G'];
        my @t = splice(@l,$sequence[$i]);  
       #TODO
    }
}
```

The error is occurring at the last line, saying that:

`Global symbol "@sequence" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my @sequence"?`

It was my understanding that Perl does not take parameters in the form `subroutine(param1, param2)` like in Java for example, but why is `$sequence` not being recognized as already having been initialized?

Comment: You use `$sequence[0]`, but you have not declared `@sequence`. In Perl, `$sequence` and `@sequence` are two different variables

Comment: Also, the assignment `$i=$HD` is probably not what you meant. Normally some kind of comparison goes there.

Comment: `$sequence[0]` is how you access an element of an array named `@sequence`. Perl correctly notes that it doesn't know anything about a variable named `@sequence`. You are likely passing an array *reference*, which should be accessed with a dereferencing arrow: `$sequence->[0]`

Answer (score 4):

There are some problems with your code:

```
sub generate_d_neighbors{
    my ($sequence, $HD) = @_;

    for(my $i = 0; $i=$HD; $i++){
        my @l = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G'];
        my @t = splice(@l,$sequence[$i]);  
    }
}
```

First, let's look at

```
    for(my $i = 0; $i=$HD; $i++){
```

Assuming `$HD` is nonzero, this loop will never terminate because the condition will never be false. If you wanted `$i` to range from `0` to `$HD`, writing the statement as `for my $i (0 .. $HD)` would have been better.

Second, you have

```
        my @t = splice(@l,$sequence[$i]);
```

where you seem to assume there is an array `@sequence` and you are trying to access its first element. However, `$sequence` is a reference to an array. Therefore, you should use

```
$sequence->[$i]
```

Third (thanks @Ikegami), you have

```
        my @l = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G'];
```

in the body of the `for`-loop. Then `@l` will contain a single element, a reference to an anonymous array containing the elements `'A'`, `'C'`, `'T'`, and `'G'`. Instead, use:

```
my @l = qw(A C T G);
```

I am not sure exactly what you want to achieve with `splice(@l, $sequence->[$i])`, but that can be better written as:

```
 my @t = @l[0 .. ($sequence->[$i] - 1)];
```

In fact, you could reduce the two assignments to:

```
 my @t = qw(A C T G)[0 .. ($sequence->[$i] - 1)];
```

Comment: @ikegami Thank you for pointing those out. I am not sure if the usage of `splice` in the original snippet is what the OP intended, but taking it at face value, I tried to incorporate your feedback.

Comment: The splice line was intended to remove the base at the current position. Example, `$sequence = "ATG";` and `$HD = 1;`  At position 0, I want to remove `A`, and be left with just `C T G`. Similarly for positon 1, remove `T` and be left with `A C G`, etc.

Comment: So, is `$sequence` a simple scalar or a reference to an array?

Comment: @SinanÜnür a reference to an array, yes. So that I'll be able to input a sequence (array) into `generate_d_neighbors` and replace each position's letter of the sequence with the 3 other possible letters.

Comment: `splice(@x, 2)` deletes everything from index 2 on. It seems you need `grep`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you want

```
substring($sequence, 0, 1)
```

instead of

```
$sequence[0].
```

In Perl, strings are first class variables, not a type of array.

Or maybe you want `splice(@l, $sequence->[0])`?

Comment: Whoops, just edited the question. Meant to be `$i` and no 0

Answer (score 0):

This list-assignment syntax:

```
my (@sequence, $HD) = @_;
```

doesn't do what you might want it to do (put the last argument in `$HD` and the rest in `@sequence`). The array always takes all the arguments it can, leaving none for whatever comes after it.

Reversing the order can work, for cases where there is only one array:

```
my ($HD, @sequence) = @_;
```

and you make the corresponding change in the caller.

To solve the problem more generally, use a reference:

```
my ($sequence, $HD) = @_;
```

and call the sub like this:

```
generate_d_neighbors(\@foo, $bar);
```

or this:

```
# Note the brackets, which make an array reference, unlike parentheses
# which would result in a flat list.
generate_d_neighbors([...], 42);
```

If you use a prototype:

```
sub generate_d_neighbors (\@$)
```

then the caller can say

```
generate_d_neighbors(@foo, $bar);
```

and the `@foo` automatically becomes a reference as if it had been`\@foo`.

If you use any of the reference-based solutions, you must alter the body of the function to use `$sequence` instead of `@sequence`, following these rules:

1. Change `@sequence` to `@$sequence`
2. Change `$#sequence` to `$#$sequence`
3. Change `$sequence[...]` to `$sequence->[...]`
4. Change `@sequence[...]` to `@$sequence[...]` (but be sure you really meant to use an array slice... if you're new to perl you probably didn't mean it, and should have used `$sequence[...]` instead)